# Why do I need to set a layout manager for my Java Swing app?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

This Java code uses Swing to display one month of a calendar:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Calendar extends JFrame {
    JLabel days[] = new JLabel[31];
    JLabel days_of_week[] = new JLabel[7];
    JLabel month = new JLabel("July 2014");`

    Calendar() {
        super("Calendar");
        setSize(260, 260);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel monthPane = new JPanel();
        monthPane.add(month);
        add(monthPane);
        JPanel days_panel = new JPanel();
        GridLayout calLayout = new GridLayout(6, 7);
        days_panel.setLayout(calLayout);
        String[] dayNames = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            days_of_week[i] = new JLabel(dayNames[i]);
            days_panel.add(days_of_week[i]);
        }        
        JLabel blank1 = new JLabel();
        days_panel.add(blank1);
        JLabel blank2 = new JLabel();
        days_panel.add(blank2);
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; ++i) {
            days[i] = new JLabel("" + (i + 1));
            days_panel.add(days[i]);
        }
        add(days_panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Calendar cal = new Calendar();
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I delete the line `setLayout(new FlowLayout());`, the calendar title disappears. Isn't FlowLayout the default? Why do I have to explicitly set it for the code to work properly?

Comment: `FlowLayout` is the default for `JPanel`, `BorderLayout` is the default for `JFrame`...fun isn't :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Isn't FlowLayout the default?
```

Wrong, the default layout of the Jframe is `BorderLayout`.

**Solution:**

if you want to remove the Flowlayout then you need to specify the position where the JPanel will be placed

**sample:**

```
JLabel blank1 = new JLabel();
    days_panel.add(blank1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JLabel blank2 = new JLabel();
    days_panel.add(blank2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: *"Wrong, the default layout of the Jframe is BorderLayout."*  It **used** to be that `JFrame` defaulted to a `FlowLayout`..

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a FlowLayout like explained here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

After that you are adding your other layouts through `add` to this FlowLayout.
But if you don't set FlowLayout you are adding to an undefined layout and setting what you add as layout.

This means your second `add` is overwriting your first `add` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a solution with the `MigLayout` manager.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutCalendar extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutCalendar() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Calendar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        String[] dayNames = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", 
            "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };        

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("ins dialog, wrap 7"));

        pnl.add(new JLabel("July 2014"), "spanx 7, center, wrap");

        for (String dn : dayNames) {
            pnl.add(new JLabel(dn));
        }

        pnl.add(new JLabel("1"), "skip 2");

        for (int d=2; d<=31; d++) {
            pnl.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(d)));
        }

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutCalendar ex = new MigLayoutCalendar();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As we can see, it is cleaner and requires less code. The spaces are automatically
handled by the manager. Due to the usage of the `FlowLayout` manager, you cannot call
the `pack()` method--it will put the top label to the right. The usage of the `setSize()` method might be OK on your computer and your OS, but almost surely it will be incorrect on some other platform.

[image: MigLayout calendar]